# Will AutoIt file upload automation work in headless mode

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, autoit

AutoIt file upload works in normal mode but AutoIt is not working in headless mode

Answer (score 0):

AutoIt can't be used to click on a headless browser. However, if the form is a standard file upload, you should be able to sendKeys() in selenium to send the path of the file to the input.

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[type='file']")).sendKeys("/Users/me/Desktop/file.txt");
```